# Saving outputs and errors of a program in text files while using Screen in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen

How can I save the errors and outputs of a program running in the background terminal handled by Screen app in a text file in Ubuntu terminal?

I use the following structure but it does not save anything in the text file:

```
Screen -m -d <command here>  &>errorOut.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`screen` comes with an inbuilt option to save all bash output into a log file.
Try running `screen` with `-L`
i.e,

```
screen -L -m -d <command here>
```

This will save the output into a separate file of the format `screenlog.x`
where x is a number.